# Rotate UIImageView 1 degree

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimageview, xcode6

I have this code for rotate image view:

```
func rotateAgain(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
        delay: 0.0,
        options: .CurveLinear,
        animations: {self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageView.transform, 1.degreesToRadians)},
        completion: {finished in if self.rotating { self.rotateOnce() }})
}
```

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument for the `CGAffineTransformRotate` is for the angle, but it is in radians, if you want to transform radians to degrees, you have to multiply the angle in degrees with **0.0174532925**

**Example for rotating for 240 degrees:**

```
CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageView.transform, 240 * 0.0174532925)
```

Comment: Why can´t i only use 240? What is "0.0174532925"?.. And for 360 degrees is: self.imageView.transform, 360 * 0.0174532925?

Comment: Yes, exactly, radians and degrees are different units, you should read a bit about that...

Comment: Do i really need both the rotate once, and rotate again? How can i do this by using only 1 function to rotate it?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus How do i rotate it 1 degree only?

Comment: If using his extension, then 1.degreesToRadian

Comment: Like: animations: {self.imageView.transform = 1.degreesToRadian}, ?

Comment: No, like: animations: {self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageView.transform, 1.degreesToRadians)},

Comment: @DejanSkledar Look at my question. I have updated it. The code does not work.

Comment: Throws  an error ? 1 degree is probally to small to notice.

Comment: @DejanSkledar To small? My plan is to make the image view rotate 360 degrees 10 times, and then rotate from a random degree between 1 and 360 degrees.

Comment: @DejanSkledar - Can you post a new answer with a full code i can try, mine is just messed up with loads of errors now.

Comment: @DejanSkledar i have code: self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageView.transform, 1 * 0.0174532925) that will rotate 1 degree. But i want to make lucky wheel, so it has to rotate more then 1 degree

Comment: Then you have to use the arc4rand() function, to generate a random degree.